# WPF mediaElement disappearing after some time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, memory-leaks, mediaelement

I have a user control with a WPF MediaElement and an Image control. This user control is again used in a few more user control which uses this in two differnt layouts. The application is supposed to show a list of videos and images for a long period of time in loops. Each user control will be loaded for a particular time period and after that time, this will be unloaded and the next control will be loaded. When the videos are running every now and then the position of the video is changed to show a particular part of the video.

XAML Code. The MediaElement is inside a Grid with one column and one row.

```
 <MediaElement Volume="0" Name="m1" Stretch="Fill" Visibility="Hidden"  LoadedBehavior="Manual" UnloadedBehavior="Manual"  />
```

C# Code, setting source

```
            this.mediaElement.Source = item.Path;
            this.mediaElement.Position = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
            this.mediaElement.Play();
```

C# Code changing position. This position change is done using a DispatcherTimer

```
            t = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Position);
            mediaElement.Position = t;
```

C# Code disposing the MediaElement. I use this code to dispose the MediaElement because previously I found out after playing for a while the MediaElement was using too much memory and becomes frozen after a while.. The below code fixed that issue.

```
        mediaElement.Close();
        mediaElement = null;
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

The application works fine, but the problem is after some time (like 20 mins) the WPF MediaElement disappears. The application works smoothly (It doesn't get frozen), the images are shown, but the MediaElement is gone.

When this problem occurred, I did some debugging and found these.

- The WPF MediaElement visibility is Visible. The Source has correct filenames. The MediaElement is not hidden behind any other controls.
- However the actual width and actual height are shown as 0.

I checked all the code to find out where the height and width becomes zero. But could not find any. So I decided to try and override the Height and Width evey millisecond using a DispatcherTimer (Just to check if it was possible). But even then the 0 in actual height and width remained the same.

Also, the application doesn't seem to use excessive memory and everything else seems to be fine.

Does anyone got a clue as to why this is happening? Any solutions or workarounds? Thanks

Comment: have you tried hardcoding the width and height of mediaElement?

Comment: @SaadAbdullah I tried hard coding but still the problem occurs.

Comment: you haven't attached the event MediaOpened to mediaElement..

Comment: It can be a GC problem, have you checked taskmanager, the usage of RAM ?....moreover,i suggest you to switch to some other player as wpf mediaelement is buggy...you can use VLC bindings (wpf) in wpf, it also gives you more flexibility like reading video frames and audio samples...i can just guess the possible issues without code...

Comment: @SaadAbdullah ty for your replies. Yes I haven't attached the MediaOpened event. Is it a must to attach this event? Also I tried removing the GC part, yet the problem persisted. Then I removed the media position part and then it worked properly. So finally I've come to the conclusion, that the problem is created by changing the position often. When the video position is being changed frequently something very wrong is happening in the MediaElement it seems. I am  trying to find a solution or a workaround.

Comment: @SaadAbdullah I checked the Ram and CPU usage and everything seems to be normal. Also in the application I change layouts in regular intervals and when this change occurs a new instance of the MediaElement is created. Even then the problem persists. In other words, after the problem appears, it doesn't even help even if a new instance of the MediaElement is created. It works only when I restart the application.

Comment: on position change method...have you tried try catch....and console or show exception in message box...i bet it will solve the problem

Comment: @SaadAbdullah Yes, I have tried and no Exception is thrown. Eveything seems to be correct except for the height and width of the MediaElement

Comment: maybe the issue is of creating new instance again and again when layout  changes....the thing you can try is attach Media Opened and Error events and console log when it opens or close or throws exception...moreover, try checking before seeking,u can use CanSeek property of mediaElement

Comment: @SaadAbdullah ty Now I've narrowed the issue down. It happens only when I play images and videos in a loop and try to adjust the position of the video. Looks more like a logical error. So rechecking everything again. I tried your suggestion but was unsuccessful in finding a clue.